# An interpretation of special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, velocity

Consider a 4-dimensional space $\mathrm{S}$ in which *all* objects move at the same speed $c_S$ but in different directions. For the objects A and B that move in directions $\overrightarrow{u_A}$ and $\overrightarrow{u_B}$, respectively, if $\Delta x$ is the distance that B moves in the (3-dimensional) space perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{u_A}$ during a time interval $\Delta T$, the distance it moves in the direction of $\overrightarrow{u_A}$ will be
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{c_S^2 \Delta T^2 - \Delta x^2} =  \sqrt{c_S^2 - v^2} \Delta T,
\end{equation*}
where $ v = \Delta x / \Delta T$. Let $\Delta \tau$ be the quantity such that
\begin{equation*}
 c_S^2 \Delta T ^2 =  v^2 \Delta T^2 + c_S^2 \Delta \tau ^2.
\end{equation*}

Thus, if $\overrightarrow{u_A}$ is *interpreted* as constituting the coordinate temporal axis and the 3-dimensional space perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{u_A}$ as constituting the coordinate space, and if $c_S=c$ is the speed of light, then the last equation describes the motion of the object B in a special relativity spacetime traveling with speed $v$ during the coordinate time interval $\Delta T$, and that $\Delta \tau$ is the proper time interval experienced for B:
\begin{equation*}
\Delta \tau = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}  \Delta T.
\end{equation*}

Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes. It is often written that the squared four velocity is 0 for light and 1 for all massive objects.

Comment: But the velocity in 3-dimensional space according to this interpretation is not $v$, it is the ratio between the 3-dimensional distance (first expression) and the temporal distance $\Delta x$

Comment: There is indeed some sort of difficulty here, I see that you try to introduce the interpretation of $\overrightarrow{u_A}$ as time towards the end. But even in the first part you mention movement along that direction in a time interval $\Delta{T}$. im not sure if that's only confusing or a real inconsistency

Comment: @amit and JDelaney: Thank you for your comments and pointing out the confusing part. I sincerely apologize. The post has been edited accordingly.

Comment: I think the general idea is correct. But I'm not sure this is really a different interpretation of SR, rather, I think that as @ConnorBehan mentioned, you are just starting from the postulate that $4$ velocities are normalized to $c$, at least for massive objects (or $1$ depending on convention) and then working out the consequences from there. Still it's interesting, you deduced time dilation from it, can you do the same for length contraction?

Comment: @Morteza I still don't see how this works. Now the 3-dimensional velocity is the ratio between $\Delta x$ and the temporal distance which is the first expression, so it is still not $v$.

Comment: @J.Delaney I think $v$ only becomes a speed in the sense we usually define it after OP identifies $\overrightarrow{u_A}$ with the purely temporal direction in the last part

Comment: I can't make sense of this question. You say that all objects move at the same speed but then A and B move at different speeds. You say that A and B move perpendicularly in three space but then you calculate how B moves in the direction of A.

Comment: @Amit The distance in the $u_A$ direction is given by the first expression, so if this is identified as time and not $\Delta T$, the velocity is not $v$.

Comment: @J.Delaney It's not exclusive, $A$ is moving purely along the time direction meaning it is at rest, and $B$ moves wrt to $A$ a distance $\Delta x$ in *coordinate* time $\Delta T$

Comment: Can you clarify the definition of "perpendicular"?

Comment: @robphy I think OP just means a decomposition of vector $\Delta \vec{x}$ with magnitude $c\Delta T$ that $B$ moves by into a component parallel to $u_A$ and one that's orthogonal/perpendicular to it. He calls $\Delta x$ the orthogonal component and calculates the parallel

Comment: @Amit I don't follow. If this picture is to be mapped to SR, some quantity here needs to be identified as coordinate time in minkowski space. it can be the distance along the $A$ direction or $T$, but it can't be both.

Comment: @J.Delaney I *think* I see what you mean now.. I think basically for this picture to make sense, $\Delta T$ and $\Delta x$ must be intervals measured by $B$, since as you said $A$'s time interval that corresponds to $\Delta T$ is already defined by the calculated distance... idk, maybe the OP can clarify :)

Comment: @J.Delaney $\overrightarrow{u_A}$ merely forms the temporal _axis_, coordinate time is $\Delta T$. However A and B both move the same distance $c\Delta T$ in the 4-D space. If $\overrightarrow{u_A}.\overrightarrow{u_B}= \cos{\theta}$, B moves with speed $v=c \sin{\theta}$ in the 3-D space ($\perp$ to $\overrightarrow{u_A}$). For example if $\overrightarrow{u_A} \perp \overrightarrow{u_B}$, B moves with speed $c$ in both 4-D and 3-D spaces. Does this help at all? At any case I hope to find out where confusion arises and  a way to more adequately address the concerns.

Comment: This site is for asking questions about mainstream physics, not for feedback about personal theories

Comment: By choosing different interpretations of what $\Delta x$ is, in your scheme, you can get either of Newtonian result or SR result. You have thus included too little detail for us to judge if this is an acceptable interpretation.

Comment: @Morteza The temporal axis *by definition* measures coordinate time, so your comment is not clear. You need to edit the question to provide all of those missing details with precise definitions. As it is written now, it is impossible to understand what you mean.